# import data repeatedly into Django models using python and SQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, csv

I researched about importing csv data into Django models and there was no mention of SQL. I just want to check if this method has any problem.

I have many csv files which need to be uploaded into MySQL database every day. I wrote a python and SQL script to clean the data and then save them into MYSQL database and this works fine.

I want to use the data to generate some charts to display in Django. I don't want to use two databases. So I would like to store the data in Django models. My question is if it is fine to create an app and models in Django and continue to use the python and SQL script to insert data. Can I use MYSQL workbench to create the tables of my data and do I have to use Django models.py to create the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Integrating Django with a legacy database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/legacy-databases/) article in the docs shows you how to get started with building a Django application on an existing database. Essentially, there's an [inspectdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb) command that you can use to generate models.

This will get a bit trickier if you then later modify your database tables outside of Django again, especially if you've made changes to your Django models in the mean time too. If you don't ever modify the models that `inspectdb` generates for you, it could work for you to just always run `inspectdb` after you've made changes to your database. Otherwise you'll have to manually change the generated models.

On a small scale this is probably doable. However, if your app is meant to be used in a business or by multiple developers, I'd suggest you start using Django's models and migrations to change your database's structure after the first time you ran `inspectdb`.

Comment: thanks. Just to double check. After migration, as long as the models' schemas are not changed, I can still use the python script (with some modifications to match the names if necessary) to insert the data into the models? The insertion is a bit complicated and I use the python script to pick up all the csv files in an ftp folder, clean up and call stored procedures to insert with some criteria. I plan to schedule the script to run at a certain time daily. I am not sure if the same can be achieved within django relatively easily so would prefer keeping running the script if possible.

Comment: Yeah, you shouldn't have to modify your Python script.